# How to change TextMate's ^H keybinding to delete instead of showing help?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I come from an Emacs background, and I'm used to typing ^H to delete the previous character. TextMate displays bundle help instead. I have not found a way to change this binding. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the bundle editor, <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and go to the textile bundle, the command for "show documentation" has the `^H` key equivalent, you can change it there.  You can then make your own key binding command for `^H`.

Comment: I erased all bindings for ^H, and it still looks for some documentation. Too sad.